# Difference between torch.flatten() and nn.Flatten()

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, tensor, difference

What are the differences between `torch.flatten()` and `torch.nn.Flatten()`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Flattening is available in three forms in PyTorch

- As a tensor method (*oop style*) [`torch.Tensor.flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=flatten#torch.Tensor.flatten) applied directly on a tensor: `x.flatten()`.
- As a function (*functional form*) [`torch.flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html?highlight=flatten#torch.flatten) applied as: `torch.flatten(x)`.
- As a module (*layer `nn.Module`*) [`nn.Flatten()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html?highlight=flatten#torch.nn.Flatten). Generally used in a model definition.

All three are identical and share the same implementation, the only difference being `nn.Flatten` has `start_dim` set to `1` by default to avoid flattening the first axis (usually the batch axis). While the other two flatten from `axis=0` to `axis=-1` - *i.e.* the entire tensor - if no arguments are given.

Comment: is it still true that flatten uses reshape beneath in C code?

Comment: Found this: [`torch/csrc/utils/tensor_flatten.h`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c9cae1446f9a9509406238a946b1735fe36a73e3/torch/csrc/utils/tensor_flatten.h#L10). Seems like it uses `view`, which is a reshape!

Answer (score 5):

You can think of the job of `torch.flatten()` as to simply doing a flattening operation of the tensor, without any strings attached. You give a tensor, it flattens, and returns it. That's all there to it.

On the contrary, `nn.Flatten()` is much more sophisticated (i.e., it's a neural net layer). Being object oriented, it inherits from `nn.Module`, although it [internally uses the plain tensor.flatten() OP in the `forward()` method](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/flatten.py#L40) for flattening the tensor. You can think of it more like a syntactic sugar over `torch.flatten()`.

---

**Important difference**: A notable distinction is that `torch.flatten()` *always* returns an 1D tensor as result, provided that the input is at least 1D or greater, whereas `nn.Flatten()` *always* returns a 2D tensor, provided that the input is at least 2D or greater (With 1D tensor as input, it will throw an [IndexError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError)).

---

#### Comparisons:

- `torch.flatten()` is an API whereas `nn.Flatten()` is a neural net layer.
- `torch.flatten()` is a python *function* whereas `nn.Flatten()` is a python *class*.
- because of the above point, [`nn.Flatten()` comes with lot of methods and attributes](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html)
- `torch.flatten()` can be used in the wild (e.g., for simple tensor OPs) whereas `nn.Flatten()` is expected to be used in a `nn.Sequential()` block as one of the layers.
- `torch.flatten()` has no information about the computation graph unless it is stuck into other graph-aware block (with `tensor.requires_grad` flag set to `True`) whereas `nn.Flatten()` is always being tracked by autograd.
- `torch.flatten()` cannot accept and process (e.g., linear/conv1D) layers as inputs whereas `nn.Flatten()` is mostly used for processing these neural net layers.
- both `torch.flatten()` and `nn.Flatten()` return *views* to input tensor. Thus, any modification to the result also affects the input tensor. (See the code below)

---

**Code demo**:

```
# input tensors to work with
In [109]: t1 = torch.arange(12).reshape(3, -1)
In [110]: t2 = torch.arange(12, 24).reshape(3, -1)
In [111]: t3 = torch.arange(12, 36).reshape(3, 2, -1)   # 3D tensor
```

Flattening with `torch.flatten()`:

```
In [113]: t1flat = torch.flatten(t1)

In [114]: t1flat
Out[114]: tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])

# modification to the flattened tensor    
In [115]: t1flat[-1] = -1

# input tensor is also modified; thus flattening is a view.
In [116]: t1
Out[116]: 
tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, -1]])
```

Flattening with `nn.Flatten()`:

```
In [123]: nnfl = nn.Flatten()
In [124]: t3flat = nnfl(t3)

# note that the result is 2D, as opposed to 1D with torch.flatten
In [125]: t3flat
Out[125]: 
tensor([[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
        [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])

# modification to the result
In [126]: t3flat[-1, -1] = -1

# input tensor also modified. Thus, flattened result is a view.
In [127]: t3
Out[127]: 
tensor([[[12, 13, 14, 15],
         [16, 17, 18, 19]],

        [[20, 21, 22, 23],
         [24, 25, 26, 27]],

        [[28, 29, 30, 31],
         [32, 33, 34, -1]]])
```

---

tidbit: `torch.flatten()` is the precursor to `nn.Flatten()` and its [brethren](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/flatten.html) [`nn.Unflatten()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Unflatten.html) since it existed from the very beginning. Then, there was a legitimate [use-case for `nn.Flatten()`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/2118), since this is a common requirement for almost all ConvNets (just before the softmax or elsewhere). So it was added later on in the [PR #22245](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/22245).

There are also recent [proposals to use `nn.Flatten()` in ResNets](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/3331) for model surgery.