# Passing the output from the last Convolutional layer to the FCC layer - PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, multidimensional-array, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to pass the output from the last Convolutional Layer to FCC layer but I am struggling with dimentions. As a default, the network uses **AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(6, 6))** what does not let me use **torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)** for reproducibility purpose. This is the error I am getting:

```
*mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0*
```

```
    (10): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(6, 6))
  (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
    (1): Linear(in_features=9216, out_features=4096, bias=True)
```

The input tensor is:  **[10, 3, 350, 350]**.
The shape of tensor from last Conv2d/MaxPool2d layer is: **torch.Size([10, 256, 9, 9])**. I assume that number of inputs for FCC should be 256 x 9 x 9 = 20736 but it does not work as well.

Here is also my class for forwarding the output from CONV to FCC layer:

```
class Identity(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Identity, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        print('SHAPE', np.shape(x))
        return x
```

The idea has been taken from video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaDe0qQZ5AQ&t=301s.
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR; The number of neurons in your fully connected layer is fine, your shape is not.**

1. The [`nn.AdaptativeAveragePool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d.html) layer between your CNN and classifier will output a tensor of shape `(10, 256, 6, 6)`. since you've initialized it with an `output_size` of `(6, 6)`. This being said, the first fully connected layer should have `256*6*6` neurons.

   ```
   self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=9216, out_features=4096)
   ```

This matches your current model's setup, not your proposed `20736`...

2. Your classifier input shape should be flattened, this can be done by defining a flatten layer [`nn.Flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html) (or using [an inline alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65993494/difference-between-torch-flatten-and-nn-flatten/65994247#65994247)). First define your layer in the initializer:

   ```
   self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
   ```

   Then

   ```
   >>> x.shape # nn.AdaptativeAveragePool2d output
   torch.Size([10, 256, 6, 6])

   >>> self.flatten(x)
   torch.Size([10, 9216])
   ```

Comment: But I want to replace _nn.AdaptativeAveragePool2d_ for _Identity()_ to pass the output from the last layer from **feature** to **classifier**. Should I use the same idea?

Comment: If you remove the adaptive average pool, then you need to change the fully connected layer, yes. Did you have the average pool removed when you got the error message?

Comment: Yes, I did. And the output from the last layer from _feature_ was [10, 256, 9, 9]

Comment: Then you have to set the fully connected to `20 736` neurons, and reshape the tensor between the CNN and classifier with the flatten layer as described in *2.**  of my answer.

Comment: Ok, done. Everything works perfect! Thank you so much!