# Batch Size in training loop of a CNN model is not matching

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Here is my CNN model, this is for a grayscale image that is 400x400:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class MModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MModel, self).__init__()
        
        # Define convolutional layers
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0)
        
        # Calculate the size of the flattened feature map before the fully connected layers
        self.fc_input_size = 64 * 200 * 200
        
        # Define fully connected layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.fc_input_size, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 18)  # Adjust the output size based on your requirements
        
    def forward(self, x):
        # Apply convolutional and pooling layers
        x = self.pool(nn.functional.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(nn.functional.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        
        # Flatten the feature map
        x = x.view(-1, self.fc_input_size)
        
        # Apply fully connected layers
        x = nn.functional.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        
        return x

# Create an instance of the CNN model
model = MModel()
```

and here is my training loop:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Training loop
num_epochs = 10

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    running_loss = 0.0

    for i, data in enumerate(train_DL, 0):
        inputs, labels = data

        # Zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(inputs)

        # Calculate the loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        # Backward pass and optimization
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()

        if i % 10 == 9:  # Print every 10 mini-batches
            print(f"[{epoch + 1}, {i + 1}] Loss: {running_loss / 10:.3f}")
            running_loss = 0.0

print("Training finished")
```

When running this code, i get this error, my batch size is 32 for my DataLoader:

```
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (8) to match target batch_size (32).
```

I tried changing the batch size to 8, which still gave me a value error. Also other solutions found on StackOverflow don't seem to be working.

Comment: What is the input resolution: 200x200?

Comment: @Ivan the input resolution is 400x400 with 1 channel

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the output shape of the 2nd pooling layer is 64x100x100, *not* 64x200x200.

Generally speaking, you don't want to fiddle with the first dimension (the batch dim) otherwise you may have this kind of problem. So an alternate way to handle this is to use a [`nn.Flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html) layer, [see details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65993494/difference-between-torch-flatten-and-nn-flatten):

```
def forward(self, x):
    # Apply convolutional and pooling layers
    x = self.pool(nn.functional.relu(self.conv1(x)))
    x = self.pool(nn.functional.relu(self.conv2(x)))

    # Flatten dimensions starting at dim=1
    x = x.flatten(1)

    # Apply fully connected layers
    x = nn.functional.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = self.fc2(x)
    
    return x
```